# Creating custom function in separate php file which is accessible from controller

Tags: php, function, this, opencart2.3

I want to write a function for catalog->controller->checkout->cart.php in Opencart 2.3.0.2
I have already written a logic to check priduct_id and action to be taken if particular product id is found.
Now I want to take this logic in separate function in separate php file so that it will become more manageable.

I created function in php file under system->helper and loaded it from startup.php.
Then I can call this function from cart.php but reference to variable $this is lost even if I am passing $this to this function.

My stripped down code looks like this
cart.php

```
//some code before this
  if (!$json) {
                // Check if Product is Addon
                 test($this);
        //more code after this
```

customfunction.php

```
    function test($this) {  
    // print_r("Test Called");
    $temp = $this->request->post['product_id'];
    if ($this->request->post['product_id'] == 142) {
                    $json['success']   = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
                    $product_options   = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->post['product_id']);
                    $product_option_id = $product_option['product_option_id'];
//more code
```

I am getting error  for

```
$this->request->post['product_id'];
```

Can someone tell me how to call custom function from separate php file preserving reference to $this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this` is reserved word in php:

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from
>   within an object context.

Try that instead:

```
function test($ctrl) { 
    $temp = $ctrl->request->post['product_id'];
    if ($ctrl->request->post['product_id'] == 142) {
    ...
```